# ADK eclipse bundle installation inconsistency

Tags: adt

Just tried (several times) to install ADT bundle for Win 7 64 bit.

adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030

It downloads and unpacks OK, and Eclipse runs, but it has trouble finding Java imports and some of the ADK subdirectories seem to be in the wrong place or have the wrong name.

I expect it's my fault, but I can't seem to figure it out. The web page it comes from warns against moving the directories around, so I'm reluctant to mess with them.

I've been developing for about a year on a 32 bit XP, but I've had to change desktop to a win 7 64bit machine, and the errors occur when I open the project I had been building on the 32 bit version. I get errors on all the #import lines, and a 'cannot find {directory-name}'.

As I write this, it occurs to me that the previous version of ADT probably had built in assumptions about paths, and I may have to start the project anew, and import the source and xml files from the old project. Groan...

Is this likely?

Comment: Post more details, like the specific errors you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! Having checked the version inconsistency question, I found that I had to

1 Start Eclipse with a new Workspace

2 IMPORT the existing project.
 File > New > Project... > Android Project from Existing Code  [Browse]

3 Check 'copy in existing Workspace’ i.e. the new workspace I defined in 1.

There were still a few inconsistencies with graphics, but I can fix these.